# Exponential convergence of p-method $u'' + u = 2 \sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation

Consider the problem
\begin{equation}
-u'' + u = 2 \sin(x) \mbox{ in } (0, \pi), \hspace{2mm} u(0) = 0, u'(\pi) = -1.
\end{equation}
I want to show that a solution of the problem satisifies the following: For every $b > 0$ there exists $K_b > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\inf_{v \in \mathcal{P}_n}(||u-v||_{L^{\infty}(0,\pi)} + ||(u-v)'||_{L^{\infty}(0,\pi)}) \leq K_b e^{-bn} \mbox{ for all } n \in \mathbb{N}_0. 
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ of degree $= n$.
The solution is $u(x) = \sin(x) \in C^{\infty}(0,\pi)$. For the approximation I use the approximation at chebyshev nodes by chebyshev polynomials
\begin{equation}
|u(x) - p_{n-1}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n \max_{\xi \in (0,\pi)}|u^{(n+1)}(\xi)| \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n  .
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
||u - p_{n-1}||_{L^{\infty}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n .
\end{equation}
I stuck at estimating $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^n$ to get the result above for some given $b > 0$. I tried using the stirling formula for $n!$ but this didn't work for me.

Comment: For your information, you can solve analytically the equation.

Comment: u(x) = sin(x) would be the solution.

Comment: and with this solution, you can prove easily what you want to prove, right?

Comment: Yes, by using the taylor series of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: But what if I consider a weak solution of the given problem. This doesn't have to be the analytical solution.

Comment: What do you mean by considering the ‘weak solution’? What is the weak solution here?

Comment: The solution $u$ that satisfies the variational formulation 
$\int^{\pi}_{0}u'\varphi' +  \int^{\pi}_{0}u\varphi = 2 \int^{\pi}_{0}{\sin(x) \varphi}$ for all $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(0,\pi)$
with $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(\pi) = 0$ where $u'$ is the weak derivative of $u$ and $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(\pi)$ means the evaluation of $u$ or $u'$ by using the trace operator and a continuous representative of $u$.

Comment: in this case you should rewrite the question and ask "I want to show that a weak solution of the problem **written below** satisifies the following"

Comment: You can't replace $u$ by $u-v$ in the third equation from the top.

Comment: Right. If I instead look at the analytical solution I would get  $||u - I_h u||_{L^{\infty}(0,\pi)} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{8}\sup_{x \in (0,\pi)}|u''(x)|$ and using the cea lemma $\inf_{v \in \mathcal{P}_n}||u-v||_{H^1} \leq ||u - I_h u||_{H^1}$ I can get estimates for $||u - v||_{L^{\infty}}$ and $||(u - v)'||_{L^{\infty}}$. But I can't see how this leads to exponential convergence. Maybe there is some way to use the gronwall lemma.